# NodeJS: Every audio file created through fs.writeFile and Blob has excessive length

Tags: node.js, mp3, fs, wav, writefile

I'm creating an app which needs to take the user's voice and convert it to text, but the audio file seems to have something wrong with the length after it's creation.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BjT1.png) is how I'm gathering the audio and converting the data to a Blob. I'm just using the getUserMedia method to record the audio and convert it to a Blob when its stopped.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBIRt.png) is the beginning of the function I pass the Blob object to. I convert the Blob to a buffer and write that buffer to a file in the root directory of my project. But once the file has been written and I go to listen to it, the length of the audio is 435:13:24 no matter how long the original audio was. But even though the length is that long, the file sounds exactly like it should and ends at the correct time.

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95L9J.png) Heres a picture of what the file looks like when viewed.

Although this may not seem like a big deal since listening to the file provides the correct audio, I'm passing the file to an API that converts it to text, and it almost always gives either the wrong translation or an error about the file containing nothing. I've tried different ways of writing the Blob data to the file, and tried cutting off the excess length audio, but nothing has worked.

This is my first post on stack overflow since I ran out of options to fix this, so I'm sorry if the question is kind of vague or I formatted it incorrectly in some way.